# person vs. personality

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> I am most eager to apply for your position of ........ **because I am a person with  an exact, efficient and dynamic leadership personality** and I am also good in time, financial and organisation managment. I am hardworking, and quick to pick up new skills.

What can I say instead of "I am a person with x,y,z personality"

For example, is it right if I say:

> "........because I am an exact, efficient and dynamic leadership person"

Answer (score 1):

Take out the word *person* out altogether:

> *...because I am an exact, efficient, and dynamic **leader***

Comment: Thank you for the answer                           if i remove the " dynamic leadrship"  which one will be correct ".... because I am an exact, efficient person and also good in .... " or "because i am exact and efficient and also good in ..."

Comment: Of course you are a person. You are not a bear or zebra! Leave out the word person. Use something more specific (like _worker_, or _employee_), or do what you did in your last example. (By the way, it's very hard to take your questions seriously if you can't even bother to capitalize "I".)